# Word Automization Service Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created an event receiver for word automization service to convert docx to pdf document. Upto 50 MB files are converted successfully, but if I am uploading large file than it shows below error.

> Error loading and running event receiver
>   TestSharePointProject.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1 in
>   TestSharePointProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=44d44ba5ed86b8c3. Additional information is below.
>
> : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>
> Event ID:6875

Below is my code to convert docx to pdf

```
SPSite spSite = null;
try
{
    bool retVal = true;
    WriteLogToFile("DocumentLibraryName(in PDF Generation : " + pDestinationDocumentLibName);
    string wordAutomationServiceName = "Word Automation Services";
    ConversionJob job = new ConversionJob(wordAutomationServiceName);
    spSite = new SPSite(pSourceSiteUrl);
    job.UserToken = spSite.UserToken;
    job.Settings.UpdateFields = true;
    job.Settings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
    string filename = pSourceFilename.Split(new char[] { '.' })[0] + ".pdf";
    job.AddFile(pSourceSiteUrl + "/" + pSourceDocumentLibName + "/" + pSourceFilename,
        pDestinationSiteURL + "/" + pDestinationDocumentLibName + "/" + filename);

    job.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ConversionJobStatus status = new ConversionJobStatus(
            wordAutomationServiceName, job.JobId, null);
        if (status.Count == status.Succeeded + status.Failed)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    spSite.Dispose();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //LogErrorToList(_lstError, ex.Message);
    WriteLogToFile(ex.Message);

}
finally
{
    if (spSite != null)
        spSite.Dispose();
    WriteLogToFile("Finlly");
}
```

Comment: This is a custom event reciever that is failing, so dig in the event receiver code!

Comment: But same code is working when file size is less than 50 MB but when file size is greater than 50 MB than it is failing.Any Reason?

Comment: Could be a change in the logic for Automation service, for example converting in chunks etc.

Comment: I have added by code base. It was working upto less than 50 MB file but not working for big file

Comment: In conversion Job status it is giving failed. How to check for what reason conversion fails

Comment: It was giving 65535 error. I have check in Word Automation Database.